# Unfamiliar use of 'new' for memory allocation (C++)

Tags: c++

I am working on some legacy code. I have the following data types:

```
typedef struct {

    char        *name ;

    ColumnType  type ;

    unsigned    pos ;    //column position in table

    CellData    **data ; //ptr to list of cells in column

}Column ;

struct _table {

    char name[TABLE_NAME_LEN+1] ;

    unsigned int num_rows ;

    unsigned int num_cols ;

    Column  **cols ; //ptr to list of columns

};



struct _table m_
```

In the source code, there is the following statement:

```
m_table.cols = new Column*[m_table.num_cols];
```

I am familiar with new[], but I'm no sure what the multiplication operator is doing there - can any explain?

Comment: It's not multiplication. They're allocating an array of `num_cols` pointers to `Column` objects.

Comment: `Column*` is pointer to `Column`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan D'Oh!. I'm embarrased I had to ask this question. I can't believe I mistook a pointer for multiplication!. I've definitely been staring at this screen for too long - time for a break!

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli This one of the reasons why I don't like C or C++. The overloading of `*` does nothing for me. Perhaps I just need to try harder!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not multiplication. The symbol `*` has many, many completely different meanings in C++, all depending on context.

In your case, you're creating a dynamic array of `Column*`, i.e. of pointers to `Column`.

In other words, you're saying `new T[N];`, where `T = Column*`.

Comment: Yup, I get it now. I plead temporary insanity for thinking a pointer was multiplication operator!. Methinks its time for a nice hot cup of cofee and a brisk walk around the office :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a multiplication operator.  It's instead allocating an array of `Column*` (pointer to `Column` type).  The resulting array stores pointer values

```
m_table.cols = new Column*[m_table.num_cols];
m_table.cols[0] = Column();  // Error: Expected Column* got Column
m_table.cols[0] = new Column();  // Ok
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `Column*` is a type (for pointers to instances of `Column` class) and you create an array of them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a multiplication operator.  It's allocating an array of pointer-to-`Column`, rather than an array of `Column`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a multiplication operator, it's a pointer specification i.e. "pointer to Column".

Answer (score 0):

The `*` denotes a pointer. So you're creating an array of `Column` pointers.